# CI with Maven, Git and Artifactory

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I want to create a CI pipeline using Maven, GitLab and Artifactory.

I already set up all these systems, and right now Jenkins makes a build, if a user pushes to GitLab and deploys the artifact to Artifactory.

But what I want is the following:

The developer develops a Java application and can push his code to GitLab. At the point when he is finished he uses the maven-release-plugin and executes the release:prepare and release:perform goal. The Maven release plugin automatically creates a new Tag and edits the version. Now Jenkins should start a new job, build the artifact and deploy it to Artifactory.

So the main thing I have to do is teaching Jenkins only to build Tags. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to activate the [Maven release](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) plugin with Jenkins and to build the release with a dedicated Jenkins job:

[image]

[image]

This job will launch the prepare and perform goals, and will upload the release binary in Artifactory (via a dedicated post-build step).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I also considered to do so. Do you have to trigger the release manually via the webfrontend?

Comment: Yes you trigger the release via the dedicated "Perform Maven Release" button.

Comment: The plugin is not working for me. When I use the command line everythings works fine, but when I start the release with jenkins maven works until the deploy goal. It says "uploading" but nothing happens...

Comment: Your Jenkins server has the relevant credentials to publish in Artifactory?

Comment: Yes, I already swiched to the jenkins user and executed `mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform` and it worked. Only Jenkins has some problems...

Comment: Maven fails with `Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact <my-artifact> from/to artifactory-central (<url>): Failed to transfer file <filename>`